# Better way to conditionally call multiple webservices from MDT CustomSettings.ini?

Tags: web-services, mdt, mdt-2013

I've got an MDT deployment which does things a little differently based on the network location. From one of the locations, I have two webservices I need to call. My initial failed attempt was:

```
[Settings]
Priority=DefaultGateway

[DefaultGateway]
10.0.0.1=LOCATION_A
10.100.0.1=LOCATION_B

[LOCATION_A]
Subsection=WebService1
Subsection=WebService2

[WebService1]
WebService=http://contoso.com/webservice1

[WebService2]
WebService=http://contoso.com/webservice2
```

I quickly discovered this doesn't work, because you can only have one subsection in a section. So the best I could come up with was to have one webservice call another. This works, but now as the webservices evolve and have other callers, I have to maintain multiple copies of some services (that is, both chained and unchained). For example,

```
[Settings]
Priority=DefaultGateway

[DefaultGateway]
10.0.0.1=LOCATION_A
10.100.0.1=LOCATION_B

[LOCATION_A]
Subsection=WebService1AndWebService2

[WebService1]
WebService=http://contoso.com/webservice1

[WebService2]
WebService=http://contoso.com/webservice2

[WebService1AndWebService2]
WebService=http://contoso.com/webservice1
Subsection=WebService2
```

So I've got two places now where I have to maintain WebService1's url, parameters, etc.

Is there a better way within CustomSettings.ini? Should I just resort to calling the webservices manually from the task sequence instead of trying to pull this off from CustomSettings.ini?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a better way. This lets you easily enable/disable the web services you want to call from different DefaultGateways, but you won't be able to customize the ordering differently between them.

```
[Settings]
Priority=DefaultGateway,FLAG_WebService1,FLAG_WebService2
Properties=FLAG_WebService1,FLAG_WebService2

[DefaultGateway]
10.0.0.1=LOCATION_A
10.100.0.1=LOCATION_B

[LOCATION_A]
FLAG_WebService1=FLAG_YES_WebService1
FLAG_WebService2=FLAG_YES_WebService2

[FLAG_YES_WebService1]
WebService=http://contoso.com/webservice1

[FLAG_YES_WebService2]
WebService=http://contoso.com/webservice2
```